# How can I get the Last-modified header on a https website?

Tags: networking, https, network-monitoring, linux-headers

I'm trying to trigger a last-modified response from a https website, but all I get is

```
301 Moved Permanently
```

[image: telnet output]

The above only works on websites with http and I can't figure out why it won't work for https.

The header I've sent on both cases, is:

> telnet kupdf.net 80

> GET /download/netzwerk-a1-kursbuch_59ce3ec508bbc5765a686f41_pdf/ HTTP/1.1

> Host: kupdf.net

> User-agent: Mozilla/4.0

> Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg

> If-modified-since: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 10:18:09 GMT

Comment: Usually `Moved Permanently` reply from Apache is returned when there is a record in Apache configuration that forwards non-secure requests on port 80 to the secure URL of the same website on port 443 with SSL.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access HTTPS sites with the `telnet` command, because they need encrypted communication and `telnet` is only for unencrypted TCP connections. For this, you need "https-aware" command-line tools like `wget` or `curl`. Please, try one of the following commands:

```
curl --header 'If-Modified-Since: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 10:18:09 GMT' \
  https://kupdf.net/download/netzwerk-a1-kursbuch_59ce3ec508bbc5765a686f41_pdf
```

or

```
wget --header 'If-Modified-Since: Fri, 30 Apr 2021 10:18:09 GMT' \
  https://kupdf.net/download/netzwerk-a1-kursbuch_59ce3ec508bbc5765a686f41_pdf
```

However, I do not believe that the site or "web page" you are trying to access supports the `If-Modified-Since` request header, because there is a high probability that the "web page" is created and served dynamically.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also used the same exact curl command before posting here, and got the page's html, css and javascript code. So if it's created dynamically there's no way to find out when it was last modified?

Comment: Please, open the relevant page in Firefox and then select **Tools** |  **Page Info**. If the **Modified** field shows the current date and time, then there is no way I know how to help you.

Comment: You're right it doesn't support that request header, just tried on Firefox dev tools. Thanks for your tips though!

Comment: @NickNameNick How did you check if it supports that request header "Last-Modified-Header" or not?